# Can't do 50k insertion using bulkCreate

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Using [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) **v4.38.0** with mysql dialect i can't do large scale insertion in database like 50k record, although it should be solved and merged on this PR [#7391](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/7391).

I've tried to use **v4.44.0** but no gain even when using `{raw: true}`
ex: `Model.bulkCreate(MY_ARRAY_50k_SIZE, {raw:true})`

I noticed that it actually executed as separated insert sql queries !!!

Could you help me to find a proper way to insert such a big bulk of data in O(1) as only one insert statement or even O(N) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can *greatly* improve performance by using a `transaction` so that the bulk insert is not committed until the end. Individual queries should not be much slower than one giant query as long as you are using a transaction.

```
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction();
await Model.bulkCreate(MY_ARRAY_50k_SIZE, { raw: true, transaction });
await transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks @doublesharp.. still the complexity is huge and i need more than 4 mins !! and the request fails. :(

Comment: @AbdallahOkasha there are a lot of other factors at play so it's hard to say for sure but it could be the size of the data, the IO speed, server memory, memory allocated to the db, etc